# Show elements containing a certain css class using angularjs filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an angularjs app. I have a checkbox in my html :

```
<input ng-true-value="Paused" ng-model="paused" type="checkbox">Show Paused
```

When I click this checkbox it should only display the elements having the `class='paused'`.
for eg let's say this is my view:

```
<span class="paused">1</span>
<span class="notpaused">2</span>
<span class="notpaused">3</span>
```

So when I click on Show Paused I want that only the `<span>` with `class="paused"` be visible in the view. other elements should be hidden from the view. I know how to use filters in angularjs but I'm not able to figure out how to do it when we have to filter by class name.
Any suggestions on how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work like this :

```
<input ng-true-value="'Paused'"  ng-false-value="''" ng-model="paused" 
type="checkbox">Show Paused

<div ng-repeat="x in users|filter:paused" >

//tip for beginners > ng-class="{'paused': x.stat == 'Paused',
'notpaused': x.stat == 'notPaused'}" assigns the class paused/notpaused 
and {{x.id}} prints the value 1.

<span class="paused">1</span> 

<span class="notpaused">2</span>
<span class="notpaused">3</span>
</div>
```

Earlier when I used to set `ng-true-value="Paused"` it would always return true hence my filter was not working as the value of `ng-model="paused"` would evaluate to `true/false` instead of Paused when the checkbox is checked. But when I included the single quotes like this : `ng-true-value="'Paused'"` , my filter is now working perfectly. Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing the value of pause variable using your ng-model, it will give result as  true or false.

so, you can use it like

```
    <span ng-if="paused">1</span>
    <span ng-if="!paused">2</span>
    <span ng-if="!paused">3</span>
```

or with your logic.